# Prevent deallocating an object defined in function

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

A function on a UIViewController declares and initializes a reference to a class object. That class has a weak delegate ref. which has been set to the UIViewController. After this function finishes execution the object gets deallocated and its no longer calling the delegate methods.

```
func registerDevice() {
    prepareForLoading(true)

    let notificationModel: NotificationModel = NotificationModel(delegate: self)

    notificationModel.registerDevice()
}
```

Is there a way to keep this object alive until the UIViewController dies, without having a global class ref. on the UIViewController to it. This is important because there isn't any use for this object in any other function or in any other situations.

Comment: Why don't you just store the notificationModel in a properes of the viewcontroller?

Comment: If the lifetime of the class is tied to the lifetime of the UIViewController, it would make sense to store it's reference in an instance variable on the UIViewController

Comment: because its never used outside of the function. and only gets used in this single situation.

Comment: but, I find it annoying that this object only get used in this function and have it as a class property. what do you think?

Comment: Well under arc, the static analyzer will inject the release call if no other object is having an owning relationship. As others suggested, use a property

Comment: First, it wouldn't be  a *class property*, or a global.  it would be an *instance property*, and it doesn't matter that the model isn't used explicitly in any other function; it is used implicitly because your view controller implements the delegate methods.  Creating an instance property is a perfectly correct solution

Comment: so they didnt invent something in swift that can own that instance in situation like this? this was the question.

Comment: Yes, it is called an instance property the same as in Objective C or Java or many other languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are declaring `notificationModel` as a constant within the scope of the `registerDevice` function, the lifetime of that object is limited to that function in the absence of any other strong reference being held.

You say "there isn't any use for this object in any other function or in any other situations.", but this isn't correct; Since your view controller implements delegate functions for this object and you expect those delegate functions to be called, your view controller needs to take responsibility for keeping the model object in memory.

It can do this by simply declaring an *instance property*

```
var notificationModel: NotificationModel?
```

and assigning the object to that property in your function:

```
func registerDevice() {
    prepareForLoading(true)

    self.notificationModel = NotificationModel(delegate: self)

    self.notificationModel!.registerDevice()
}
```

Now the lifetime of your model object is (at least) the lifetime of your view controller.

Note, that this property is not a class property or a global; it is scoped to the specific View Controller instance.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did upvote it. so you are confirming there is no other way?

Comment: You could make `NotificationModel` a singleton, so it holds a strong reference to itself. The lifetime of the object is then the lifetime of your app